# Using JQuery/JSON to update a selection list--JQuery code execution seems to halt

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the following JQuery code in an attempt to populate a dropdown list:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#setStatusDrpDown").change(function(){
    $.getJSON("getStatusChangeReasons", 
              {selectedStatusId: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, 
               function(result) {
              alert("here");
              for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
              alert("hello");
              options += '<option value="' + result[i].id + '">' + result[i].changeReason + '</option>';
  }
              $("select#statusChangeReason").html(options);
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

I know that the code is running because I can see my controler intercept it and even print the selectedStatusId value. What I cannot figure out is why neither of my alerts are displayed. I don't see any errors on the javascript console. Its as if code simply quits execution after the controller. Any advice is apprecaited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service might be throwing an error or returning something that $.getJSON can't understand.

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error,
>   the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of
>   JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with
>   syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object
>   literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON,
>   whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in
>   double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.
>
> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

You can handle the error withe xhr return value.

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("example.json", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: You are right, it is indeed alerting that there is an error. I am returning a hashset of objects, and each object has the .toString method overridden so that it can be treated as a JSON, but apparently I am still doing something wrong.

Comment: Do I have to return the ArrayList or HashSet as a JSON object?

Comment: This answer led me well on my way. My problem now is some sort of circular reference when attempting to import the jackson library, but that's a new question altogether.